# Angular Input binding causing compile error despite importing forms module

Tags: angular

I have created the simplest of apps to try and resolve this issue
in app.component.html I have the following:

```
<input type="text" [(ng-model)]="test">
```

In app.component.ts I have this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  test:any;
}
```

And finally in app.module I have imported the FormsModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So I have no idea why I can't use the two way binding on the input. I get the error "can't bind to ng-model since it is not a known property of input" that everyone else seems to have solved by merely importing the forms module

Comment: I think, you use wrong name for `ng-model`, change to `[(ngModel)]="name"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an AngularJs syntax in Angular. You need to replace the

```
[(ng-model)]
```

to

```
[(ngModel)]
```

For more info have a look at the official documentation
https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test">
```

not ng-model